# Assigning grades to scores in an array, but keep getting incorrect grades assigned

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, mean

If grades are calculated like this:

```
A = mean + standard <= score
B = mean+(standard/3) <= score < mean+standard
C = mean - (standard/3) <= score < mean+(standard/3)
D = mean - standard <= score < mean - (standard/3)
F = score < mean - standard
```

How would I assign each `score({65.0, 80.3, 70.2, 20.1, 93.2})` in an array of length 5, a letter grade? Mean and `standard(65.8, 27.70)` are already calculated, but I'm having trouble with how I would calculate the following in `if` statements. I know that java can't compare **a < b < c**, but even when I add parents and group them, I get wrong grade assignments to each individual score.

Any help would definitely by appreciated. I also know that a for-loop to go through each score is needed.

Comment: Let's see your code attempt. Otherwise how can we tell what you might be doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that java can't compare a < b < c

**No** You can, java can do many things :

You can compare your values like this:

```
if(a < b && b < c){
   //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use and (&&) in between comparisons..
Like for example:

```
if((mean + (standard/3))<=score) && (score < (mean+standard)){

//assign grade to B

}
```